# How get media from IG

Tags: android, api, instagram-api

until yesterday everything worked as expected but now seems like that the API of Instagram has changed.

I usually performed a request to ig like this
'https://www.instagram.com/anyuser/media' and the result was a json list with the latest 20 pictures.

Now that url don't work anymore. 
My question is, there is any easy way to get the photos only from 1 user. Because I need to show my latest pictures in Instagram in my android app. Thanks for the time

Comment: Can you show us the code that you are currently using to make the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an alternative way with https://www.instagram.com/anyuser/?__a=1

I reposted it, because mods deleted my previous post, without a reason.